# What is the Most Effective Modelling/Sculpting Method for this Reference?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

hope we're all well!

Was in the process of modelling this 2D styled vintage hand cartoon. With this model, I'm up to modelling the palm of the hand, and as you can see in the 2D reference there's a lot of round creases.

From the tutorials I've watched online the method I've attempted is;
• Use some spheres to create a rough outline of the overall shape
• Then re-topologies the mesh by having "snap to face" as a guide, and right-clicking and drawing out the individual vertices with a more even form and geometry

I've found this method a little challenging and was curious to know if anyone else had any other different methods they would use to tackle this?

Naturally from this question, I am quite a beginner and would love to know how everyone else would approach this to open me up to different ways this problem can be solved.

One idea I had was to draw a simplified rectangle version of the palm, with a subdivision modifier and then draw a distinct edge around the creases and then bevel that edge to replicate the rounded look from the 2D illustration.

Thanks in advance for everyone's help!

*UPDATE*

On the third image across, I've changed the overall shape with a cube and a subdivision modifier. But I'm struggling with how to make the right "incisions" within the inner creases of the palms to get those creases I'm obsessing over.

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can get a definite answer to this. There is no one most effective way for everyone. For a skilled modeler modelling will be the most effective way for a skilled sculptor, sculpting will be more effective. It depends on what techniques you are more used to. Even very skilled modelers will often chose very different ways to model things even if they achieve very similar results in similar time. You should just ask for a good way to model it, not for "the best", because there is no such thing.

Comment: If you wanted to model it, I would personally recommend starting with the fingers and then working your way towards the palm. The fingers kind of define the shape and if you model the palm first it'll be harder to match the same idea of the shape. I think it would be easier to model than to sculpt it as well there are a lot of different masses to work with and you want them all to be perfectly smooth and curved.